# Add multiple columns to R data.table in one function call?

Tags: r, data.table

I have a function that returns two values in a list. Both values need to be added to a data.table in two new columns. Evaluation of the function is costly, so I would like to avoid having to compute the function twice. Here's the example:

```
library(data.table)
example(data.table)
DT
   x y  v
1: a 1 42
2: a 3 42
3: a 6 42
4: b 1  4
5: b 3  5
6: b 6  6
7: c 1  7
8: c 3  8
9: c 6  9
```

Here's an example of my function. Remember I said it's costly compute, on top of that there is no way to deduce one return value from the other given values (as in the example below):

```
myfun <- function (y, v) 
{
ret1 = y + v
ret2 = y - v
return(list(r1 = ret1, r2 = ret2))
}
```

Here's my way to add two columns in one statement. That one needs to call myfun twice, however:

```
DT[,new1:=myfun(y,v)$r1][,new2:=myfun(y,v)$r2]

   x y  v new1 new2
1: a 1 42   43  -41
2: a 3 42   45  -39
3: a 6 42   48  -36
4: b 1  4    5   -3
5: b 3  5    8   -2
6: b 6  6   12    0
7: c 1  7    8   -6
8: c 3  8   11   -5
9: c 6  9   15   -3
```

Any suggestions on how to do this? I could save `r2` in a separate environment each time I call myfun, I just need a way to add two columns by reference at a time.

Comment: Why not have your function take in a data frame and return a data frame directly? `myfun <- function (y, v) 
{
ret1 = y + v
ret2 = y - v
return(list(r1 = ret1, r2 = ret2))
}

Comment: @Etienne Because that copies the inputs to create a new output. Florian is using `data.table` for its memory efficiency with large datasets; it doesn't copy `x`,`y` or `v` at all, even once. Think 20GB datasets in RAM.

Answer (score 107, accepted):

Since `data.table` v1.8.3, you can do this:

```
DT[, c("new1","new2") := myfun(y,v)]
```

Another option is storing the output of the function and adding the columns one-by-one:

```
z <- myfun(DT$y,DT$v)
head(DT[,new1:=z$r1][,new2:=z$r2])
#      x y  v new1 new2
# [1,] a 1 42   43  -41
# [2,] a 3 42   45  -39
# [3,] a 6 42   48  -36
# [4,] b 1  4    5   -3
# [5,] b 3  5    8   -2
# [6,] b 6  6   12    0
```

Comment: wow, that second one is amazing, thanks! just ran it with `debug(myfun)` to see how often it gets called: it's once. great.

Comment: +10 from me too. I've just raised [FR#2120](https://r-forge.r-project.org/tracker/index.php?func=detail&aid=2120&group_id=240&atid=978) to "Drop needing `with=FALSE` for LHS of `:=`"

Comment: Note that list recycling is also done; e.g., `c("a","b","c","d"):=list(1,2)` puts 1 into `a` and `c`, and 2 into `b` and `d`. If any of the columns don't exist they'll be added by reference. Not sure how useful `:=` recycling is in practice. It's more for `c("a","b","c"):=NULL` which deletes those 3 columns. Internally that's a recycle of NULL to a (semantic) list length 3.

Comment: @MatthewDowle oh yes, just wanted to ask that. the `c("a","b","c"):=NULL` is very useful.

Comment: another useful `:=` usage can be `\`:=\`(colname=colvalue,...)`. I often prefer this one because you might just replace `:=` with `list` to have a read-only preview of data to be written by reference when `:=` used.

Comment: Note that `dt[, c(...):=fun(...)]` works, but `dt[, c(...)=fun(...)]`doesn't. But you can just to `dt[, fun(...)]` and then `setnames(dt, c('V1', 'V2', ...), c('name1', 'name2', ...))`

Comment: @jangorecki, I think your solution should be the preferred method. It is just that the question is old, and maybe this solution did not exist back then. Please add as an answer, so we can upvote it

Comment: The second syntax is clearly better than chaining n assignments, esp. for arbitrarily long function with n return values. Suggest you move it to the top.

Comment: I came here looking for an analog to plyr's ddply. This answer is not that! It passes the whole columns y and v to myfun, instead of doing it row-by-row. See Vasco's answer for a solution, https://stackoverflow.com/a/44266413/553434.

Answer (score 4):

The answer can not be used such as when the function is not vectorized.

For example in the following situation it will not work as intended:

```
myfun <- function (y, v, g) 
{
  ret1 = y + v + length(g)
  ret2 = y - v + length(g)
  return(list(r1 = ret1, r2 = ret2))
}
DT
#    v y                  g
# 1: 1 1                  1
# 2: 1 3                4,2
# 3: 1 6              9,8,6

DT[,c("new1","new2"):=myfun(y,v,g)]
DT
#    v y     g new1 new2
# 1: 1 1     1    5    3
# 2: 1 3   4,2    7    5
# 3: 1 6 9,8,6   10    8
```

It will always add the size of column `g`, not the size of each vector in `g`

A solution in such case is:

```
DT[, c("new1","new2") := data.table(t(mapply(myfun,y,v,g)))]
DT
#    v y     g new1 new2
# 1: 1 1     1    3    1
# 2: 1 3   4,2    6    4
# 3: 1 6 9,8,6   10    8
```

Answer (score 2):

To build on the previous answer, one can use `lapply` with a function that output more than one column. It's is then possible to use the function with more columns of the data.table.

```
 myfun <- function(a,b){
     res1 <- a+b
     res2 <- a-b
     list(res1,res2)
 }

 DT <- data.table(z=1:10,x=seq(3,30,3),t=seq(4,40,4))
 DT

 ## DT
 ##     z  x  t
 ## 1:  1  3  4
 ## 2:  2  6  8
 ## 3:  3  9 12
 ## 4:  4 12 16
 ## 5:  5 15 20
 ## 6:  6 18 24
 ## 7:  7 21 28
 ## 8:  8 24 32
 ## 9:  9 27 36
 ## 10: 10 30 40

 col <- colnames(DT)
 DT[, paste0(c('r1','r2'),rep(col,each=2)):=unlist(lapply(.SD,myfun,z),
                                                   recursive=FALSE),.SDcols=col]
 ## > DT
 ##     z  x  t r1z r2z r1x r2x r1t r2t
 ## 1:  1  3  4   2   0   4   2   5   3
 ## 2:  2  6  8   4   0   8   4  10   6
 ## 3:  3  9 12   6   0  12   6  15   9
 ## 4:  4 12 16   8   0  16   8  20  12
 ## 5:  5 15 20  10   0  20  10  25  15
 ## 6:  6 18 24  12   0  24  12  30  18
 ## 7:  7 21 28  14   0  28  14  35  21
 ## 8:  8 24 32  16   0  32  16  40  24
 ## 9:  9 27 36  18   0  36  18  45  27
 ## 10: 10 30 40  20   0  40  20  50  30
```

Answer (score 1):

In case a function return a matrix you can achieve the same behavior by wrapping the function with one converting the matrix into list first. I wonder if data.table should handle it automatically?

```
matrix2list <- function(mat){
unlist(apply(mat,2,function(x) list(x)),FALSE)
}

DT <- data.table(A=1:10)

myfun <- function(x) matrix2list(cbind(x+1,x-1))

DT[,c("c","d"):=myfun(A)]

##>DT
##      A  c d
##  1:  1  2 0
##  2:  2  3 1
##  3:  3  4 2
##  4:  4  5 3
##  5:  5  6 4
##  6:  6  7 5
##  7:  7  8 6
##  8:  8  9 7
##  9:  9 10 8
## 10: 10 11 9
```

Answer (score -5):

Why not have your function take in a data frame and return a data frame directly?

```
myfun <- function (DT) 
{
DT$ret1 = with(DT, y + v)
DT$ret2 = with(DT, y - v)
return(DT)
}
```

Comment: Because that copies the whole of `DT`, twice. Florian is using `data.table` for its memory efficiency with large datasets; it doesn't copy `x`,`y` or `v` at all, even once.