# Assign multiple columns using := in data.table, by group

Tags: r, dataframe, data.table, variable-assignment, colon-equals

What is the best way to assign to multiple columns using `data.table`? For example:

```
f <- function(x) {c("hi", "hello")}
x <- data.table(id = 1:10)
```

I would like to do something like this (of course this syntax is incorrect):

```
x[ , (col1, col2) := f(), by = "id"]
```

And to extend that, I may have many columns with names stored in a variable (say `col_names`) and I would like to do:

```
x[ , col_names := another_f(), by = "id", with = FALSE]
```

What is the correct way to do something like this?

Comment: This looks like it has been answered:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11308754/add-multiple-columns-to-r-data-table-in-one-function-call

Comment: Alex, That answer is close but it doesn't seem to work in combination with `by` as @Christoph_J is correct to say. Link to your question added to [FR#2120](https://r-forge.r-project.org/tracker/index.php?func=detail&aid=2120&group_id=240&atid=978) "Drop needing with=FALSE for LHS of :=", so it won't get forgotten to revisit.

Comment: To be clear, `f()` is a function returning multiple values, one for each of your columns.

Answer (score 196, accepted):

This now works in v1.8.3 on R-Forge. Thanks for highlighting it!

```
x <- data.table(a = 1:3, b = 1:6) 
f <- function(x) {list("hi", "hello")} 
x[ , c("col1", "col2") := f(), by = a][]
#    a b col1  col2
# 1: 1 1   hi hello
# 2: 2 2   hi hello
# 3: 3 3   hi hello
# 4: 1 4   hi hello
# 5: 2 5   hi hello
# 6: 3 6   hi hello

x[ , c("mean", "sum") := list(mean(b), sum(b)), by = a][]
#    a b col1  col2 mean sum
# 1: 1 1   hi hello  2.5   5
# 2: 2 2   hi hello  3.5   7
# 3: 3 3   hi hello  4.5   9
# 4: 1 4   hi hello  2.5   5
# 5: 2 5   hi hello  3.5   7
# 6: 3 6   hi hello  4.5   9 

mynames = c("Name1", "Longer%")
x[ , (mynames) := list(mean(b) * 4, sum(b) * 3), by = a]
#     a b col1  col2 mean sum Name1 Longer%
# 1: 1 1   hi hello  2.5   5    10      15
# 2: 2 2   hi hello  3.5   7    14      21
# 3: 3 3   hi hello  4.5   9    18      27
# 4: 1 4   hi hello  2.5   5    10      15
# 5: 2 5   hi hello  3.5   7    14      21
# 6: 3 6   hi hello  4.5   9    18      27
```

```
x[ , get("mynames") := list(mean(b) * 4, sum(b) * 3), by = a][]  # same
#    a b col1  col2 mean sum Name1 Longer%
# 1: 1 1   hi hello  2.5   5    10      15
# 2: 2 2   hi hello  3.5   7    14      21
# 3: 3 3   hi hello  4.5   9    18      27
# 4: 1 4   hi hello  2.5   5    10      15
# 5: 2 5   hi hello  3.5   7    14      21
# 6: 3 6   hi hello  4.5   9    18      27

x[ , eval(mynames) := list(mean(b) * 4, sum(b) * 3), by = a][]   # same
#    a b col1  col2 mean sum Name1 Longer%
# 1: 1 1   hi hello  2.5   5    10      15
# 2: 2 2   hi hello  3.5   7    14      21
# 3: 3 3   hi hello  4.5   9    18      27
# 4: 1 4   hi hello  2.5   5    10      15
# 5: 2 5   hi hello  3.5   7    14      21
# 6: 3 6   hi hello  4.5   9    18      27
```

---

Older version using the `with` argument (we discourage this argument when possible):

```
x[ , mynames := list(mean(b) * 4, sum(b) * 3), by = a, with = FALSE][] # same
#    a b col1  col2 mean sum Name1 Longer%
# 1: 1 1   hi hello  2.5   5    10      15
# 2: 2 2   hi hello  3.5   7    14      21
# 3: 3 3   hi hello  4.5   9    18      27
# 4: 1 4   hi hello  2.5   5    10      15
# 5: 2 5   hi hello  3.5   7    14      21
# 6: 3 6   hi hello  4.5   9    18      27
```

Comment: Thanks for this answer and the examples.  How should I modify the following line in order to get two columns for each objectName from the dim output, rather than one column with two rows? `data.table(objectName=ls())[,c("rows","cols"):=dim(get(objectName)),by=objectName]` (I'm using `data.table` 1.8.11)

Comment: @dnlbrky `dim` returns a vector so converting that to type `list` should rotate it; e.g. `[,c("rows","cols"):=as.list(dim(get(objectName))),by=objectNa‌​me]`. Trouble is that `as.list` has call overhead and also copies the small vector. If efficiency is a problem as number of groups rises then please let us know.

Comment: Thanks @Matt_Dowle.  I had tried `list` but not `as.list`.  Speed isn't an issue.  Just wanted a quick way to find objects in the environment that had a certain number of columns or rows.  This is off topic, but... what do you think about adding NCOL to `tables()`?

Comment: @dnlbrky Great idea, done. Just committed to v1.9.3 on R-Forge.

Comment: Hi Matt. The first example in your second code block (i.e. `x[,mynames:=list(mean(b)*4,sum(b)*3),by=a,with=FALSE][]`) now throws a warning, so maybe remove it?  On a related note, has anyone suggested that, with `options(datatable.WhenJisSymbolThenCallingScope=TRUE)`, an assignment like `x[,mynames:=list(mean(b)*4,sum(b)*3),by=a]` should in fact work? Seems like that would be consistent with the other changes, though I guess it might break too much existing user code (?).

Comment: @JoshO'Brien Matt removed that option in response to a bug shortly after your comment, fyi https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/issues/1952

Comment: @MattDowle can you make it such that this syntax would work too?

`x[, .(Col1, Col2) := 'somevalue']`

This is particularly useful because you can then use RStudio's autocomplete for column names as you type them.

Comment: @Merik Seems like a good idea, should be possible. Please file a feature request on GitHub [here](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/issues/new) - thanks.

Comment: I don't think by=a is necessary; not sure why it would be. I tried and it worked.

Comment: @PanFrancisco Without `by=a` it will work, but return a different answer.  The `mean(a)` and `sum(a)` aggregates are being recycled within each group when `by=a`.  Without `by=a` it just sticks the `mean` and `sum` for the entire column into each cell (i.e. different numbers).

Comment: @MattDowle what if my function already returns named list, is there anyway I can add the columns to the dt without having to name them again? e.g. f <- function(x) {list("c"="hi", "d"="hello")} will print results with named cols with x[ , f(), by = a][] . I don't know how to append the result to the dt.

Comment: @Jfly That would be a good new question which would likely lead to a feature request filed on GitHub. Perhaps something like  `x[, {ans=f(); names(ans):=ans}, by=a]`  could be implemented. That syntax conveys the intent quite nicely to my eye. What you think?

Comment: Why do you use mynames with and without parenthesis? Is there a difference?

Comment: @HermanToothrot  `mynames:=` assigns to the column called `"mynames"`. `(mynames):=` assigns to the column name held in the `mynames` variable in calling scope.

Comment: @FengJiang [`data.table` #1543](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/issues/1543) is tracking this issue and links to [multiple](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66917673/set-multiple-columns-in-r-data-table-with-a-named-list-and) [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51861038/1870254) here.

Answer (score 82):

The following shorthand notation might be useful. All credit goes to [Andrew Brooks, specifically this article](http://brooksandrew.github.io/simpleblog/articles/advanced-data-table/#create-multiple-columns-with--in-one-statement).

```
dt[,`:=`(avg=mean(mpg), med=median(mpg), min=min(mpg)), by=cyl]
```

Comment: This is so much better and more readable than the `c() := list()`