# R: dynamically generate column-parsing code for dynamically named column in data table

Tags: r, data.table

I am trying to move some old code from a data frame implementation to data table. Initially I obtain my data from a .csv file, where some cells contain arrays which are converted into character strings by fread, like so:

```
> mydata$sport[1]
[1] "[24, 18, 24, 18]"
```

I want to parse these strings into numeric arrays. Here's what I've got partly working as a first step (to get rid of the brackets, step 2, not shown here, is to convert to a numeric array):

```
> name = "ascent"
> paste0(name, ":=strsplit(gsub('^\\[|\\]$','',", name, "),',')")
[1] "ascent:=strsplit(gsub('^\\[|\\]$','',ascent),',')"
 #here I manually copy the result of paste0 into the datatable command
 #I want to automate this setup, so this all can be put in a for loop
 #for many names
> mydata[, ascent:=strsplit(gsub('^\\[|\\]$','',ascent),',')]
> mydata$ascent[10]
[[1]]
[1] "-999"  " -999"
```

So the command I generate to make the modification is good, but I have many `names` I want to do this for, so I don't want to copy and paste by hand, as is necessary above. I tried using the `eval` trick discussed here [dynamic column names in data.table, R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11745169/dynamic-column-names-in-data-table-r)

But once I introduce `eval` the code doesn't work:

```
> name = "ascent"
> mydata[, eval(paste0(name, ":=strsplit(gsub('^\\[|\\]$','',", name, "),',')"))]
[1] "ascent:=strsplit(gsub('^\\[|\\]$','',ascent),',')"
```

**So how can I implement this to work for an arbitrary name without having to create a command by hand for each desired name via paste0?** I have an entire vector of `names` where I would like to do this modification.

Here's the data table right after `fread` and before making any modifications:

```
> mydata[1:10, .(sport, ascent)]
                             sport                                                       ascent
 1:               [24, 18, 24, 18]                                   [-999, 140.0, -999, 140.0]
 2: [2, 2, 2, 22]                                                    [-999, -999, -999, -999]
 3:       [-999, -999, -999, -999]                                     [-999, -999, -999, -999]
 4:                   [-999, -999]                                               [173.0, 173.0]
 5:                       [18, 18]                                                 [-999, -999]
 6:                         [-999]                                                       [-999]
 7:                         [-999]                                                       [-999]
 8:                         [-999]                                                       [-999]
 9:                   [-999, -999]                                                 [-999, -999]
10:                   [-999, -999]                                                 [-999, -999]
```

Comment: You don't have to code that way to remove brackets for all columns. You can just `lapply(mydata, function(x) gsub('^\\[|\\]$','', x))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use the names at all...

```
for(j in which(names(mydata) %in% names)) set(mydata,i=NULL,j=j,value=strsplit(gsub('^\\[|\\]$','',mydata[[j]]),','))
```

As an aside `eval` needs `parse` to work the way you were trying to use it, for example `eval(parse(text=paste0(name,":=1+1")))`

Comment: thanks for the suggestion, but since I don't want to perform this action on all the columns and it would be awkward to have to track which column numbers rather than which column names I wanted to refer to, I don't think this solution is workable.

Comment: see edit.  This should work for vector called `names` only.

Comment: @sunny does the edit solve your problem?  If so would you mind accepting the answer?

Comment: yes the edit did solve the problem. I will accept your answer, though I am still hoping to find a way to avoid for loops.

Comment: actually if you look at the comments to the answer of this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16846380/how-to-apply-same-function-to-every-specified-column-in-a-data-table you'll find the creators of data.table prefer a for loop for this type of thing.