# Mutate data using dynamic column names in dplyr or data.table

Tags: r, dplyr, data.table

I have a data set with many rows and the following columns: an `id` column, a set of columns showing the result of one round of measurements for several values (`val1.x`, `val2.x`, `val3.x`, ...) and another set of columns showing the result of another round of measurements for the same values (`val1.y`, `val2.y`, `val3.y`, ...). Here is a reduced working example:

```
d <- data.table(
  id = 1:10,
  val1.x = c(1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0),
  val2.x = c(1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0),
  val1.y = c(0, 0, 0, 1, 0, NA, NA, 0, 1, 0),
  val2.y = c(1, 0, 0, NA, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0)
)
```

My goal is to get to a data set which lists the same columns, along with the maximum of the two measurements for each value. Here is the desired output for above example

```
    id val1.x val2.x val1.y val2.y val1.max val2.max
 1:  1      1      1      0      1        1        1
 2:  2      0      0      0      0        0        0
 3:  3      0      1      0      0        0        1
 4:  4      1      1      1     NA        1        1
 5:  5      0      0      0      0        0        0
 6:  6      1      0     NA      1        1        1
 7:  7      0      0     NA      0        0        0
 8:  8      0      0      0      0        0        0
 9:  9      1      0      1      1        1        1
10: 10      0      0      0      0        0        0
```

As evident from the example, by max I mean `max(..., na.rm = T)`. I also have a variable `cols` already prepare with this value:

```
cols <- c('val1', 'val2')
```

**The Goal**

I want to use this variable to **loop through the columns dynamically** and calculate the max.

What is a good `dplyr` way of achieving this?

What is a good  `data.table` way of achieving this?

NB: I do **not** want to use the order of columns (so solutions that reference columns by their order (e.g. `2:3`) are not desirable. The input may change and additional columns may be added to the left of the values, so I need to use the names of the columns to do the calculations. The `id` column will always be unique per row.

**What I have tried so far**

I can get the right-hand side of the equation to be dynamic using `as.symbol` like this:

```
d[, .(val1.max := pmax(eval(as.symbol('val1.x')), eval(as.symbol('val2.x'))))]
```

But I cannot get the left-hand side to become dynamic.

I also tried to implement a solution based on [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11745169/dynamic-column-names-in-data-table) but it gives me an error:

```
left <- "va1.x"
right <- "va1.y"
new <- "val1.max"
expr <- bquote(.(as.name(new)):=pmax(as.name(left), as.name(right), na.rm=T))
d[, eval(expr)]
```

Comment: If you do this one by one, isn't that more manual than the `melt` approach

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option in `data.table` is to `melt`

```
library(data.table)
d[melt(d, measure = patterns(cols))[,
    lapply(.SD, max, na.rm = TRUE), .(id), 
    .SDcols = value1:value2], paste0(cols, ".max") :=
         .(value1, value2), on = .(id)][]
#    id val1.x val2.x val1.y val2.y val1.max val2.max
# 1:  1      1      1      0      1        1        1
# 2:  2      0      0      0      0        0        0
# 3:  3      0      1      0      0        0        1
# 4:  4      1      1      1     NA        1        1
# 5:  5      0      0      0      0        0        0
# 6:  6      1      0     NA      1        1        1
# 7:  7      0      0     NA      0        0        0
# 8:  8      0      0      0      0        0        0
# 9:  9      1      0      1      1        1        1
#10: 10      0      0      0      0        0        0
```

---

Or another option without `melt`ing would be to subset the columns based on the values in 'cols', and use `pmax`

```
d[,  paste0(cols, ".max") := lapply(cols, function(pat)
     do.call(pmax, c(.SD[, grep(paste0('^', pat, '$'), 
           names(.SD)), with =  FALSE], na.rm = TRUE)))]
#    id val1.x val2.x val1.y val2.y val1.max val2.max
# 1:  1      1      1      0      1        1        1
# 2:  2      0      0      0      0        0        0
# 3:  3      0      1      0      0        0        1
# 4:  4      1      1      1     NA        1        1
# 5:  5      0      0      0      0        0        0
# 6:  6      1      0     NA      1        1        1
# 7:  7      0      0     NA      0        0        0
# 8:  8      0      0      0      0        0        0
# 9:  9      1      0      1      1        1        1
#10: 10      0      0      0      0        0        0
```

---

Or with `tidyverse`, reshape into 'long' with `pivot_longer`, do a group by `max` for multiple columns in `summarise_at` and join with the original dataset

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
d %>%
   pivot_longer(cols = -id, names_sep="[.]", names_to = c(".value", "group")) %>% 
   group_by(id) %>%
   summarise_at(vars(starts_with('val')),
     list(max = ~max(., na.rm = TRUE))) %>% 
   left_join(d, .)
#   id val1.x val2.x val1.y val2.y val1_max val2_max
#1   1      1      1      0      1        1        1
#2   2      0      0      0      0        0        0
#3   3      0      1      0      0        0        1
#4   4      1      1      1     NA        1        1
#5   5      0      0      0      0        0        0
#6   6      1      0     NA      1        1        1
#7   7      0      0     NA      0        0        0
#8   8      0      0      0      0        0        0
#9   9      1      0      1      1        1        1
#10 10      0      0      0      0        0        0
```

Comment: This is a reasonable workaround, but I am specifically looking for a solution in which dynamic column references are used. For instance, I know that I can make the right hand side of the calculation dynamic with something like `d[, .(val1.max := pmax(eval(as.symbol('val1.x')), eval(as.symbol('val2.x'))))]` but I cannot get the left hand side to be dynamic

Comment: Also, note that your data.table solution is hardcoding the number of columns it can process (in this case, only two columns, because you specified `value1, value2`). I am trying to avoid any hardcoding.

Comment: @Merik  I also provided a `tidyverse` solutioin

Comment: @Merik You can check my updated data.table solution with `pmax`

Comment: The second solution is smart. Can you please edit your solution, remove the first solution (which is limited to two columns), and also explain the logic of `.SD[, grep(pat, names(.SD)), with =  FALSE]` and why it needs a `grep`?

Comment: Also, I think the grep should be modified to `grep(paste0('^', pat, '$'), names(.SD))` so that if we happen to have other columns with partially matching names, they are not picked up