# New data.table columnS based on grouping and function of multiple columns

Tags: r, data.table

Let's say I have a `data.frame`

```
sample_df = structure(list(AE = c(148, 1789, 1223, 260, 1825, 37, 1442, 484, 
10, 163, 1834, 254, 445, 837, 721, 1904, 1261, 382, 139, 213), 
    FW = structure(c(1L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 
    3L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L), .Label = c("LYLR", 
    "OCXG", "BIYX"), class = "factor"), CP = c("WYB/NXO", "HUK/NXO", 
    "HUK/WYB", "HUK/NXO", "WYB/NXO", "HUK/WYB", "HUK/NXO", "HUK/NXO", 
    "WYB/NXO", "HUK/NXO", "WYB/NXO", "HUK/NXO", "HUK/WYB", "WYB/NXO", 
    "HUK/WYB", "WYB/NXO", "WYB/NXO", "HUK/WYB", "WYB/NXO", "WYB/NXO"
    ), SD = c(1, 1, -1, 1, 1, 1, 1, -1, 1, 1, -1, -1, 1, -1, 
    -1, 1, -1, 1, 1, 1)), .Names = c("AE", "FW", "CP", "SD"), row.names = c(NA, -20L), class = "data.frame")
```

Or in human readable format:

```
     AE   FW      CP SD
1   148 LYLR WYB/NXO  1
2  1789 BIYX HUK/NXO  1
3  1223 OCXG HUK/WYB -1
4   260 BIYX HUK/NXO  1
5  1825 BIYX WYB/NXO  1
6    37 LYLR HUK/WYB  1
7  1442 OCXG HUK/NXO  1
8   484 BIYX HUK/NXO -1
9    10 OCXG WYB/NXO  1
10  163 OCXG HUK/NXO  1
11 1834 BIYX WYB/NXO -1
12  254 OCXG HUK/NXO -1
13  445 BIYX HUK/WYB  1
14  837 OCXG WYB/NXO -1
15  721 LYLR HUK/WYB -1
16 1904 BIYX WYB/NXO  1
17 1261 LYLR WYB/NXO -1
18  382 LYLR HUK/WYB  1
19  139 LYLR WYB/NXO  1
20  213 BIYX WYB/NXO  1
```

now suppose that for each unique value `(fw,cp)` of `(FW,CP)`, I would like to get

- sum of all values of `AE` for `(FW,CP)=(fw,cp)`
- mean of all values of `SD` for `(FW,CP)=(fw,cp)`

In R, one could do something like:

```
unique_keys  <- unique(sample_df[,c('FW','CP')])
slow_version <- function(ind, sample_df, unique_keys){
    index <- which(sample_df$FW == unique_keys$FW[ind] & sample_df$CP == unique_keys$CP[ind])
    c(ind    = ind,
               sum_ae = sum(sample_df$AE[index]), 
               min_ae = mean(sample_df$SD[index]))
}
intermed_result <- t(sapply(1:nrow(unique_keys), slow_version, 
                                      sample_df = sample_df, 
                                    unique_keys = unique_keys))
colnames(intermed_result) <- c('ind','sum','mean')
result <- data.frame(unique_keys[intermed_result[, 'ind'], ], 
                    'sum' = intermed_result[,'sum'], 
                    'mean' = intermed_result[,'mean'])
```

but this gets pretty slow as the size of `data_frame` grows.

Thanks to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12758229/189035) answer, I suspect it is possible to use `data.table` magic to get the same result fastly. But doing:

```
library(data.table)
sample_dt = data.table(sample_df)
setkey(sample_dt, FW, CP)
f <- function(AE, SD) {list('sum' = sum(AE), 'mean' = mean(SD))} 
sample_dt[,c("col1","col2"):=f(AE, SD), by=.(FW, CP)][]
```

does not yield the desired result. What is the correct way?

Comment: You'll run into syntax like `DT[, .(sae = sum(AE), msd = mean(SD)), by=.(FW,CP)]` early in the vignettes. Type `vignette(package="data.table")` to see a listing or look at the website for the package under "getting started".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would try:

```
library(data.table)
sample_dt = data.table(data_frame)
setkey(sample_dt, FW, CP)
f <- function(AE, SD) {list('sum' = sum(AE), 'mean' = mean(SD))} 

sample_dt[, f(AE, SD), by=.(FW, CP)]
#      FW      CP  sum       mean
# 1: LYLR HUK/WYB 1140  0.3333333
# 2: LYLR WYB/NXO 1548  0.3333333
# 3: OCXG HUK/NXO 1859  0.3333333
# 4: OCXG HUK/WYB 1223 -1.0000000
# 5: OCXG WYB/NXO  847  0.0000000
# 6: BIYX HUK/NXO 2533  0.3333333
# 7: BIYX HUK/WYB  445  1.0000000
# 8: BIYX WYB/NXO 5776  0.5000000
```

you didn't get desired output because you assign the resulting sum and mean columns by group to original data.table with `:=`. However, I also prefer the syntax suggested by Frank, which should be the right way to go. For our current named list approach, when adding `verbose = T`, it says:

> Making each group and running j (GForce FALSE) ... The result of j is
> a named list. It's very inefficient to create the same names over and
> over again for each group. When j=list(...), any names are detected,
> removed and put back after grouping has completed, for efficiency.
> Using j=transform(), for example, prevents that speedup (consider
> changing to :=). **This message may be upgraded to warning in future**.

When we have many groups and the function in `j` are basic functions like `mean` and `sd`, using

```
sample_dt2[, .(sum.AE = sum(AE), mean.SD = mean(SD)), by=.(FW, CP)]
```

would be very fast, becaused those functions are replaced with GForce functions like `gmean` internally. see `?GForce` and  [the benchmark of Frank](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/36545111#36545111) for more information.

Comment: This is kind of esoteric but: by wrapping it in a function, you're preventing data.table from optimizing the call/query. See `?GForce` and try running your query with `verbose=TRUE` (which will warn about using a named list by group and show that GForce is not used, even though it could be here). The OP is complaining about speed, so I figure it's worth noting, anyway.

Comment: @Frank, thanks for pointing out that. It seem that when size of the data grows,  `GRorce` would be faster, but the difference is very little for this data. see the benchmark results in my edited post.

Comment: It generally shows an improvement as the number of groups grows. I posted a benchmark in the R chat room: http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/25312/r-public

Comment: Thanks! The benchmarks made me completely change my original approach!