# data.table assigning multiple columns generated as a new data.table (or list) without repeating names

Tags: r, data.table, names

My question is about error-proneness / maintainability of code when assigning  multiple columns to a data.table.

I have a function that returns a data.table like this:

```
f <- function(x)
{
  # perform some complicated operations on x yielding multiple results

  data.table(col1 = my_result_1, col2 = my_result_2)
}
```

I'm applying this function on groups of rows of another data.table and the results are added as new columns (or updates the columns if they already exist):

```
dt <- data.table(x = 1 : 4, id = c(1,1,2,2))
#    x id
# 1: 1  1
# 2: 2  1
# 3: 3  2
# 4: 4  2

dt[, c('col1', 'col2') := f(x), by = id]
```

Technically, this works fine. However, I'm wondering whether there is an elegant way that avoids having to specify the column names generated in `f()` again on the LHS of :=.

Comment: This is a little unclear to me. Generally, if you're using `:=`, you have to specify column names to assign to. How do you decide the names of the new columns? Do you have them stored in some vector that you could use?

Comment: the names are in the data.table generated in f(). I don't have them anywhere else. The problem is just, if I change anything in f() (for example adding new columns to the result data.table), I need to make sure to update the call of f() accordingly, which is a potential source of introducing errors.

Comment: Fwiw, I added a comment about it on this (I think) related issue: https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/issues/1543#issuecomment-413248490

Answer (score 0):

The OP has asked for *an elegant way that avoids having to specify the column names generated in f() again on the LHS of `:=`*.

The approach below is neither elegant nor efficient but it avoids creating new column names and it will work if the function is modified to return more columns or if the output column names are changed, Thus, it addresses the question of *error-proneness / maintainability of code* the OP has raised.

```
library(data.table)

f <- function(x) {
  my_result_1 <- x^2/sum(x)
  my_result_2 <- sum(x)/x
  data.table(col1 = my_result_1, col2 = my_result_2)
}

dt <- data.table(x = 1 : 4, id = c(1,1,2,2))
tmp <- dt[,  f(x), by = id]
dt[, names(tmp) := tmp]
dt[]
```

> ```
>    x id      col1     col2
> 1: 1  1 0.3333333 3.000000
> 2: 2  1 1.3333333 1.500000
> 3: 3  2 1.2857143 2.333333
> 4: 4  2 2.2857143 1.750000
> ```

Now, let's redefine `f()`

```
f <- function(x) {
  my_result_1 <- x^2/sum(x)
  my_result_2 <- sum(x)/x
  my_result_3 <- max(x)/x
  data.table(c1 = my_result_1, c2 = my_result_2, c3 = my_result_3)
}

tmp <- dt[,  f(x), by = id]
dt[, names(tmp) := tmp]
dt[]
```

> ```
>    x id      col1     col2        c1       c2       c3
> 1: 1  1 0.3333333 3.000000 0.3333333 3.000000 2.000000
> 2: 2  1 1.3333333 1.500000 1.3333333 1.500000 1.000000
> 3: 3  2 1.2857143 2.333333 1.2857143 2.333333 1.333333
> 4: 4  2 2.2857143 1.750000 2.2857143 1.750000 1.000000
> ```

#### Caveat

As [pointed out by Frank](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51861038/data-table-assigning-multiple-columns-generated-as-a-new-data-table-or-list-wi/51863724?noredirect=1#comment90682956_51863724), this answer works only if `f(x)` returns the same number of rows as `dt`.

Comment: I don't follow why `names(tmp) := tmp` is used. `tmp` could have fewer rows than `dt` (if `uniqueN(dt, by="id") < nrow(dt)` and `f` is aggregating), right?

Comment: @Frank, generally speaking, you are right. But OP's example has `dt[, c('col1', 'col2') := f(x), by = id]`. So, the OP already has  made sure that `f(x)` returns the same number of rows as `dt` has. The tempory assignment to `tmp` is just the trick to catch the column names used in the result of  `f(x)`.

Comment: Ok. Fwiw, the quoted line from the OP does not imply an equal number of rows by my reading. Though it's bad practice in my opinion, people often add summary stats (other than group ids like .GRP) in that way, like `f = length; data.table(mtcars)[, n := f(cyl), by=gear][]`

Comment: this doesn't work in the general case because the order of the rows in tmp isn't guaranteed to correspond to the order of the rows in dt. I think dt must be ordered by the grouping columns to get correct results (the row order within a group shouldn't matter, though).