# Assign values to multiple columns on subset using ":=" from data.table

Tags: r, data.table

Following up on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11680579/assign-multiple-columns-using-in-data-table-by-group) question, how would you assign values to multiple columns in a data table using the ":=" sign?

For example:

```
x <- data.table(a = 1:3, b = 1:6, c = 11:16)
```

I can get what i want using two lines:

```
x[a>2, b:=NA]
x[a>2, c:=NA]
```

but would like to be able to do it in one, something like this:

```
x[a>2, .(b:=NA, c:=NA)]
```

But unfortunately that doesn't work. Is there another way?

Comment: You find the answer in the documentation `help(':=')`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use the `:=` once with

```
x[a >2, `:=`(b = NA, c = NA)]
```

---

If there are many columns, another option is `set`

```
for(nm in names(x)[-1]) set(x,  i=which(x[["a"]]>2), j=nm, value = NA)
```