# Add two mutated column in a grouping by with data.table

Tags: r, data.table

I want to add two columns to the mtcars dataset and keeping all the data
If I add one column, it's work :

```
dt <- as.data.table(mtcars)

dt[, max_mpg := max(mpg), by = cyl][]
```

But when I add the second columns I have an error :

```
dt[, list(max_mpg := max(mpg), min_mpg := min(mpg)), by = cyl][]
```

I want to keep all others column, something similar to the mutate function in dplyr

Thanks

Comment: How about this: `dt[, max_mpg := max(mpg), by = cyl][, min_mpg := min(mpg), by = cyl]`?

Comment: Thanks this is what I was looking for

Comment: Cool. I have added it as an answer..

Answer (score 4):

Better yet, you can follow conventional data.table syntax and use

```
DT[, ":="(max_mpg = max(mpg), min_mpg = min(mpg)), by = cyl]
```

Answer (score 3):

You can do it using:

```
dt[, max_mpg := max(mpg), by = cyl][, min_mpg := min(mpg), by = cyl]
head(dt)

#    mpg cyl disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs am gear carb max_mpg min_mpg
#1: 21.0   6  160 110 3.90 2.620 16.46  0  1    4    4    21.4    17.8
#2: 21.0   6  160 110 3.90 2.875 17.02  0  1    4    4    21.4    17.8
#3: 22.8   4  108  93 3.85 2.320 18.61  1  1    4    1    33.9    21.4
#4: 21.4   6  258 110 3.08 3.215 19.44  1  0    3    1    21.4    17.8
#5: 18.7   8  360 175 3.15 3.440 17.02  0  0    3    2    19.2    10.4
#6: 18.1   6  225 105 2.76 3.460 20.22  1  0    3    1    21.4    17.8
```

Answer (score 2):

Maybe this is a duplicate of [Assign multiple columns using := in data.table, by group](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11680579/assign-multiple-columns-using-in-data-table-by-group)

But use

```
dt[ , c("max_mpg", "min_mpg") := list(max(mpg), min(mpg)), by = cyl][]
```