# set multiple columns in R `data.table` with a named list and `:=`

Tags: r, data.table

Using `:=` to create new columns is one of my favorite features of data.table. I know of two approaches to using it to add multiple columns at once. Here's a simple example

```
dt <- data.table("widths" = seq(2, 10, 2), "heights" = 8:4)
dt
   widths heights
1:      2       8
2:      4       7
3:      6       6
4:      8       5
5:     10       4
```

Suppose I want to add two columns, one for areas and another for perimeters. The first approach is a call such as

```
new_cols <- c("areas", "perimeters")

my_fun <- function(x, y){
  areas <- x * y
  perimeters <- 2*(x + y)
  return(list(areas = areas, perimeters = perimeters))
}

dt[ , (new_cols) := my_fun(widths, heights)]
dt
   widths heights areas perimeters
1:      2       8   16        20
2:      4       7   28        22
3:      6       6   36        24
4:      8       5   40        26
5:     10       4   40        28
```

Equivalently, we could use the functional form of `:=` as follows:

```
dt[ , `:=`("areas" = widths * heights, "perimeters" = 2*(widths + heights))]
```

Both of these approaches require entering the names of the new columns in advance. You can enter them manually,  you can save them in an object prior to creating the columns, or you could have a function on the left-hand side of `:=` that produces names. What I don't know about is a way to get both the names and output to `:=` in a single call.

Is there a way to do this? Here's an example of what I'm hoping to do:

```
dt[ , (new_cols) := NULL] # delete the previously added area and perimeter cols.
dt[ , `:=`(my_fun(widths, heights))]
dt
   widths heights areas perimeters
1:      2       8   16        20
2:      4       7   28        22
3:      6       6   36        24
4:      8       5   40        26
5:     10       4   40        28
```

Ideally, there's a way to make `:=` see that `my_fun()` returns names and then use these as the names for the new column. I know the above produces an error, but I'm wondering if there's a simple way to get the desired functionality, since this would be useful in larger problems where there are many columns or where the column names depend on the input to the function.

Edit:
The key thing I'm looking for is a way to assign these columns by reference, i.e., using `:=` or set(), and I also want to maintain the class of the output as a `data.table`.

Comment: `dt[ ,c(mget(names(.SD)),my_fun(widths, heights))]`,  or may be  `cbind(dt, dt[, my_fun(widths, heights)])`  but neither of them does any thing inplace

Comment: Thanks. The mget() options is nice but the key thing I'm looking for is the inplace updating with `:=` or set(). I've edited the question to make that clear.

Comment: I think `dt[, do.call(":=", my_fun(widths, heights))]` would theoretically do exactly what you want, but it doesn't currently work.  I've submitted an issue https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/issues/4950

Comment: Thanks for submitting the issue. Something built in would be really great, since that would allow the use of `by` and all the other data.table tools in this situation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

too long in comment. Not pretty:

```
dt[, {
    a <- my_fun(widths, heights)   
    for (x in names(a))
        set(dt, j=x, value=a[[x]])
}]
```

Or you can pass `dt` into the function if it was created by you?

Comment: Thanks for this solution. I'm accepting it since it does what I asked for. If you have any ideas on how to easily extend this to work when grouping with `by=`, that would be great.

Comment: Maybe add the by argument and i with .I

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you are looking for this but this works.

```
data.frame(dt, my_fun(dt$widths, dt$heights))

#  widths heights areas perimeters
#1      2       8    16         20
#2      4       7    28         22
#3      6       6    36         24
#4      8       5    40         26
#5     10       4    40         28
```

Unfortunately, `data.table(dt, my_fun(dt$widths, dt$heights))` doesn't work.

Comment: Thanks but this isn't quite what I'm looking for. I want to maintain the data.table class and add the new columns without copying `dt`.

Answer (score 0):

Until [#1543](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/issues/1543) is resolved, you might consider using `cbind` and reassigning if your are not limited by execution time/memory:

```r
library(data.table)
dt <- data.table("widths" = seq(2, 10, 2), "heights" = 8:4)

my_fun <- function(x, y){
  areas <- x * y
  perimeters <- 2*(x + y)
  return(list(areas = areas, perimeters = perimeters))
}

dt <- dt[, cbind(.SD, as.data.table(my_fun(widths, heights)))]
dt
#>    widths heights areas perimeters
#>     <num>   <int> <num>      <num>
#> 1:      2       8    16         20
#> 2:      4       7    28         22
#> 3:      6       6    36         24
#> 4:      8       5    40         26
#> 5:     10       4    40         28

dt <- dt[, cbind(.SD, better.name = as.data.table(my_fun(widths, heights)))]
dt
#>    widths heights areas perimeters better.name.areas better.name.perimeters
#>     <num>   <int> <num>      <num>             <num>                  <num>
#> 1:      2       8    16         20                16                     20
#> 2:      4       7    28         22                28                     22
#> 3:      6       6    36         24                36                     24
#> 4:      8       5    40         26                40                     26
#> 5:     10       4    40         28                40                     28
```

This will copy your whole data.table and will also not update existing columns with the same name but on the other hand allows you to prefix all variables.