# How to get multiple column results from function that generates a list

Tags: r, data.table

This question is similar but not identical to [Add multiple columns to R data.table in one function call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11308754/add-multiple-columns-to-r-data-table-in-one-function-call)

Let's say I have a data.table

```
ex<-data.table(AAA=runif(100000),BBBB=runif(100000),CCC=runif(100000),DDD=runif(100000),EEE=runif(100000),FFF=runif(100000),HHH=runif(100000),III=runif(100000),FLAG=c(rep(c("a","b","c","d","e"),200000)))
```

I can get the sum and mean of all the columns by doing

```
ex[,c(sum=lapply(.SD,sum),mean=lapply(.SD,mean)),by=FLAG]
```

The results look good with the names I specified in the J appended to the existing column names for easy identification with only 1 row for each of the values of `FLAG`, as expected.

However, let's say I have a function that returns a list such as

```
sk<-function(x){
  meanx<-mean(x)
  lenx<-length(x)
  difxmean<-x-meanx
  m4<-sum((difxmean)^4)/lenx
  m3<-sum((difxmean)^3)/lenx
  m2<-sum((difxmean)^2)/lenx
  list(mean=meanx,len=lenx,sd=m2^.5,skew=m3/m2^(3/2),kurt=(m4/m2^2)-3)
}
```

If I do

```
ex[,lapply(.SD,sk),by=FLAG]
```

I get results with a row for each output of the list.  I'd like to still have just 1 row of results with columns for each of the original columns and function results.

For example the output columns should be

```
AAA.mean    AAA.len     AAA.sd     AAA.skew    AAA.kurt       BBBB.mean    BBBB.len     BBBB.sd     BBBB.skew    BBBB.kurt    ....    III.mean    III.len     III.sd     III.skew    III.kurt
```

Is there a way to do this?

I know I could just put all these individual functions in the J and get the columns but I find that when I use this function instead of the individual functions for all the moments it is a good bit faster.

```
x<-runif(10000000)
system.time({
mean(x)
length(x)
sd(x)
skewness(x)
kurtosis(x)
})
user  system elapsed 
5.84    0.47    6.30

system.time(sk(x))
user  system elapsed 
3.9     0.1     4.0
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this:

```
ex[, as.list(unlist(lapply(.SD, sk))), by = FLAG]
```

Comment: +1. I wonder if there is a way to avoid coercing to list ([as recommended](http://rwiki.sciviews.org/doku.php?id=packages:cran:data.table#don_t_coerce_j_to_list_use_list_directly)). `do.call("c",...` and `Reduce("c",...` seem to be just as slow.

Comment: @Frank, `do.call("c", ...)` seems ok but `Reduce("c", ...)` has down side of losing an important part of the names.

Comment: This does work but based on @Frank's comments I wonder if there's a way to change the way the function returns results in order to improve this.