# Extract rows from R data frame based on factors (strings)

Tags: r, dataframe

Sorry if this is a duplicate, but I can't seem to find the information anywhere else on SO, even though it seems like such a simple problem. I have a data frame with several columns as factors. Some of those are integers, and some are strings. I would like to extract the rows that correspond to a particular factor. For example,

```
my_data <- read.table(file = "my_data.txt", header = TRUE)
my_data[ my_data$age == 20, ]
```

This works, but if I then try

```
my_data[ my_data$gender == "male", ]
```

This produces no matches. I realized they are not the same thing, as checking the class of `my_data$name[1]` gives factor, while I'm checking it against a string.

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong here?

Cheers

Data sample:
    Size    Age    Gender    Value
    1       20     male      0.5
    4       22     female    0.7
    3       14     female    0.3

Comment: Should we assume that you have tried to use the correct `[row, col]` extracting form, as in `my_data[my_data$gender == "male", ]`?

Comment: Could you give us a sample of your data (e.g. dput(head(my_data))?

Comment: yes, I used the `[row, col]` format....I realised my mistake now....I should have done `my_data[ my_data$gender == " male ", ]` Do you see the difference? Quite embarrassing, really.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Try using the `subset` function.

This site provides a good reference: 
[HowtoInR](http://howtoinr.weebly.com/filtering-data.html)

```
my_data = subset(my_data, gender == "male")
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. However, it gives the same output.

Comment: Could you give a sample of your data?

Comment: Thanks for that, found the problem, see my comment above. Sorry about the trouble. I knew I was doing something wrong.

Comment: This works even for boolean comparision, e.g. data$x => data$y.

Answer (score 4):

This is an answer to an old question, but I'd like to share my current way of doing things where mistakes like this happen a lot less.

The answer is the `data.table` package. It has saved me hundreds of lines of code and will continue to do so. Subsetting becomes a piece of cake:

```
my_data <- data.table(my_data)
my_data[gender == "male" & age <= 20]
```

I can string as many conditionals as I like, and also use `.SD` to pass columns as arguments to functions, like so:

```
my_data[gender == "male" & age <= 20, lapply(.SD, mean), by = c("nationality", "height")]
```

Column creation from existing columns is much simpler, even [creating multiple columns at once](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11308754/add-multiple-columns-to-r-data-table-in-one-function-call)