# Inhibit Copy On Modify In "R" Function Argument Data Tables?

Tags: r, data.table, pass-by-reference

Unqualified data tables, passed as function arguments, are modifiable without copy on modify:

```
dt<-data.table(RowId=c('a','b','c','d'),x=0:3)
f<-function(adt){adt[,x:=4]}
f(dt)
dt
#   RowId x
#1:     a 4
#2:     b 4
#3:     c 4
#4:     d 4
```

I'd like to preserve this behavior on a restricted set of rows as in:

```
f(dt[x>1])
dt
#   RowId x
#1:     a 0
#2:     b 1
#3:     c 4
#4:     d 4
```

rather than having to embed the restriction in the function or passing the restriction as an argument to be evaled within the function.

Is there a way to accomplish this?

If not, what is the most parsimonious way of replacing the rows of `dt` corresponding to those in the copy returned from the function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what I ended up doing:

`dt[f(dt[x>1]),x:=i.x,on="RowId"]`

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know you cannot.

but you can do

```
myfun <-function (x){
    4
}

dt[x>1,x:=myfun(x)]
```

Comment: Why would it be any more dangerous than the first case, which is currently permitted?

Comment: What if the `function` modifies, or even initializes, more than one column?

Comment: You are right it's not more dangerous than the first case. If you want a function that modifies more than one column Have a look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11308754/add-multiple-columns-to-r-data-table-in-one-function-call#11308946)

Comment: That looks like it's getting there with the expression `DT[, c("new1","new2") := myfun(y,v)]`, however that relies on knowing the order of the returned columns rather than on their names.

Comment: Granted but I think you can control the return order in the `myfun`

Comment: How about this: `dt[f(dt[x>1]),x:=i.x,on="RowId"]` ?

Comment: Sorry for the delay. I didn't know this specification. You should post it as an answer :-).