# Add to data.table additional values from function which returns dataframe

Tags: r, dataframe, data.table

Suppose, we have *data.table* with some columns:

```
DT <- data.table(c1 = c(1, 2, 3), c2 = c(1, 2, 3), ...)
```

and have function which returns *data.frame*:

```
fn_ret_df <- function(val1, val2) {
    return(data.frame(newC1 = val1^2, newC2 = val2/2))
}
```

How to concat initial *DT* and results of *fn_ret_df(c1, c2)* after applying for each line?

Here's what works for me now, but it has **memory consumption problem**:

```
DT[, cbind(fn_ret_df(c1, c2), c1, c2)]
```

Comment: You can't add the values using `data.table` methods? Is there a reason you're relying on another function to mutate `DT`? Working within `data.table` is usually the solution to a memory consumption problem.

Comment: As hinted in above comment, you can do this directly like `DT[, c("newC1", "newC2") := .(val1^2, val2 / 2)]`. You're `cbind` method will require multiple copies which are avoided with `:=`.

Comment: @DanHall and @lmo: The function is in a package and has a complex logic. Thus, i can't use `:=` in simple way.

Comment: Many thanks. I found solution in related questions - [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11308946/4957055)