# combining separate data.table calls into one by group call

Tags: r, performance, data.table

I'm trying to improve the efficiency of the following simple `data.table` syntax, so I'm trying to combine it into one call without repeatedly calling `by = "group"`.

```
#data
library(data.table)
DT <- data.table(group = c(rep("a", 40), rep("b", 40)),
                 other = rnorm(80),
                 num = c(1:80))

#reduce this to one "by" call
DT[, c1 := ifelse(num <= 7, NA, num), by = "group"]
DT[, sprintf("c%d", 2:10) := shift(c1, 1:9, type = 'lag'), by = "group"]
DT[, d1 := shift(c10, 1, type = 'lag'), by = "group"]
DT[, sprintf("d%d", 2:10) := shift(d1, 1:9, type = 'lag'), by = "group"]
DT[, e1 := shift(d10, 1, type = 'lag'), by = "group"]
DT[, sprintf("e%d", 2:10) := shift(e1, 1:9, type = 'lag'), by = "group"]
```

Something like

```
DT[, .(c1 := ifelse(num <= 7, NA, num),
       sprintf("c%d", 2:10) := shift(c1, 1:9, type = 'lag'),
       d1 := shift(c10, 1, type = 'lag'),
       sprintf("d%d", 2:10) := shift(d1, 1:9, type = 'lag'),
       e1 := shift(d10, 1, type = 'lag'),
       sprintf("e%d", 2:10) := shift(e1, 1:9, type = 'lag')), by = "group"]
```

Edit:

This is similar but slightly different to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11308754/add-multiple-columns-to-r-data-table-in-one-function-call) as the variables created here are not independent of one another.

Any suggestions?

Thanks

Comment: As I am aware you can not use in one `data.table` call just defined variable like in dplyr

Comment: interesting, so are you suggesting running line by line is the most efficient way? I'd have doubts as it seems repetitive. Maybe setting a key (`setkey`) alleviates some of the issues

Comment: depends on your data. Maybe setting key on `group` could yield minor improvement.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Add multiple columns to R data.table in one function call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11308754/add-multiple-columns-to-r-data-table-in-one-function-call) as well as https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11680579/assign-multiple-columns-using-in-data-table-by-group

Comment: @minem you can absolutely do multiple updates in [tag:data.table]. There are two syntaxes: ```dt[, `:=`(z1 = x, z2 = y)]``` or ```dt[, c('z1', 'z2') := .(x, y)]``` Also for @OP, please choose minimal examples.

Comment: @Cole but in your example you can not use `z1` to calculate `z2`, that is what I meant

Comment: @Cole as minem pointed out those questions assume that the variables are independent whereas in my question they are not. I had seen them but think this is slightly different

Comment: @minem i see and agree. The ```{...}``` allows for intermediate variables and it is actually how [tag:dtplyr] translates ```mutate``` .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an option:

```
ix <- 2L:10L
m <- 1L:9L
DT[, c(sprintf("c%d", ix), sprintf("d%d", ix), sprintf("e%d", ix)) := {
    c1 = replace(num, num <= 7L, NA_integer_)
    lc = shift(c1, m)

    d1 = shift(lc[[9L]])
    ld = shift(d1, m)

    e1 = shift(ld[[9L]])
    c(lc, ld, shift(e1, m))
}, group]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
# You can write function:
f <- function(num) {
  c1 <- ifelse(num <= 7, NA, num)
  cl <- shift(c1, 1:9, type = 'lag')
  names(cl) <- sprintf("c%d", 2:10)
  d1 <- shift(cl[9], 1, type = 'lag')
  dl <- shift(d1, 1:9, type = 'lag')
  names(dl) <- sprintf("d%d", 2:10)
  e1 <-  shift(dl[9], 1, type = 'lag')
  el <- shift(e1, 1:9, type = 'lag')
  names(el) <- sprintf("e%d", 2:10)
  c(c1 = list(c1), cl, d1 = d1, dl, e1 = e1, el) # list of desired columns
}

x <- DT[, f(num), by = group] # apply it by group
DT <- cbind(DT, x[, -'group']) # add to initial data
```

Maybe this will be faster. Also, the function probably could be written better. Make sure that the function return list with your desired column names.

Answer (score 1):

You can call `by` once using the fact that (1) every column in the `j` argument of a `data.table` 
becomes a column in the return data.table, and that (2) curly braces can be used for 
intermediate calculations in `j`.
Because the default value of the argument `type` in the `shift` function is `lag`, 
I did not specify it.
Note that the last line in the curly braces, `lst`, is the only object returned.

```
DT[, {
  nms = paste0(rep(c("c", "d", "e"), each = 10), 1:10)
  lst = setNames(vector("list", 30), nms) 

  lst[["c1"]] = ifelse(num <= 7, NA, num)
  lst[sprintf("c%d", 2:10)] = shift(lst[["c1"]], 1:9)

  lst[["d1"]] = shift(lst[["c10"]], 1)
  lst[sprintf("d%d", 2:10)] = shift(lst[["d1"]], 1:9)

  lst[["e1"]] = shift(lst[["d10"]], 1)
  lst[sprintf("e%d", 2:10)] = shift(lst[["e1"]], 1:9)
  lst
}, by = group]
```

The output contains 30 columns: c1, ...,c10, d1,...,d10 and e1,...,e10